# A colleague wants to leave if I would ever leave the company. How would you interpret this?

Tags: work-environment

A coworker said to me that if i would ever plan to leave the company I must tell it to her because then she would also leave. I think this is a bit weird. What do you think? How do you interpret this?

Comment: As worded, this question comes across as looking for an opinion. Please reword it to give us [A question we can address](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I voted to close this question as "Opinion Based". Can you elaborate more? And be specific on what do you want to do here.

Comment: you should give us more information about your relationship with this person: do you know him snce a while? is it your manager, or something relevant? how big is your team/company? at this state, it will be hard to write good answers

Comment: There are enough odd people with crazy motivations out there that, even if one thought it was just a "you're awesome and otherwise this place kinda sucks" sentiment, you can't really rule out some kind of bizarre attempt to curry favor by having the inside gossip, which could really screw up your career. Mr Positive covers it pretty well.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the company or your history with this other employee, this really is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 20):

> What do you think?
>   How do you interpret this?

I think this person would interpret your **departure as a bad sign for the company** and would want to leave if you do.  Further, they probably enjoy working with you.  Nothing too weird about this, and I would not dwell on it.

For what it is worth, over the years in my career there have been places I have worked where if certain key people were to leave, I would want to leave too.  Your mileage may vary.

Also, I would point out that **if** you intend on leaving do **not** tell anyone until you have an accepted offer in hand.